Plot linetype manually ggplot
I want to plot linetypes manually according to weather it is a country (objects of analysis) or a group of countries for comparison. I also renamed the observations from the country code to the name of the country for presentation reasons. That last part has worked so far, but I can't seem to know if it is causing the problem.
I have written this code:
data_pop_growth_rate_output_worker %>% filter(ref_area == "CHN" |
                                               ref_area == "PRK" |
                                               ref_area == "VNM" |
                                               ref_area == "X05") %>% 
  mutate(ref_area = recode(ref_area,
                          CHN = "China",
                          PRK = "Coreia",
                          VNM = "Vietnã",
                          X05 = "Mundo: alta renda")) %>% 
 
  
    ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = time,
                y = obs_value,
                colour = ref_area))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("China" = "#FE6100",
                    "Coreia" =  "#648FFF",
                    "Vietnã" = "#FFB000",
                    "Mundo: alta renda" = "#785EF0"
                    ))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("China" = "solid",
                    "Coreia" =  "solid",
                    "Vietnã" = "solid",
                    "Mundo: alta renda" = "dotted"
                    ))


The result is:
enter image description here
I manual scalling of linetype doesn't seem to work. The world ("mundo") area stays solid.
Tried to manually plot a dotted line type for one specific observation.

If you don't have linetype= in an aes(), then scales_linetype_ does nothing. You need to have an active mapping.

Uncertain without data, but you need to add aes(linetype=ref_area). Perhaps
    ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = time,
                y = obs_value,
                colour = ref_area,
                linetype = ref_area)) +                  ## add this
  scale_color_manual(values = c("China" = "#FE6100",
                    "Coreia" =  "#648FFF",
                    "Vietnã" = "#FFB000",
                    "Mundo: alta renda" = "#785EF0"
                    ))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("China" = "solid",
                    "Coreia" =  "solid",
                    "Vietnã" = "solid",
                    "Mundo: alta renda" = "dotted"
                    ))

